# C#: Log parsing with RegEx, want to extract some other values from the log file as well

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm kinda new to C#, and I've already submitted one question to stackoverflow, but I solved that ([C#: Log parsing date/time with regex, when there's an anomaly of >1 second, I want to save that whole line to a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49051064/8691248)).

Now, this is how the log outputs look like:

```
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000461> <RPC ID: 0072606623> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390620   > <USER: lkoporec                                     > <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:53:04.4230 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:10> Checking "SHR:LHP:InitSvc_GetServiceContextFlag" (0)
<API > <TID: 0000000373> <RPC ID: 0072606628> <Queue: List      > <Client-RPC: 390620   > <USER: Remedy Application Service                   > <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:53:06.1140 */ +BE      ARBulkEntry -- user Remedy Application Service from Normalization Engine (protocol 24) at IP address 10.122.26.197 using RPC // :q:0.1s 

<FLTR> <TID: 0000000445> <RPC ID: 0072611490> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:53:43.3600 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:3> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_3" (530)
<API > <TID: 0000000382> <RPC ID: 0072611493> <Queue: List      > <Client-RPC: 390620   > <USER: darzupan                                     > <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:53:46.5240 */ +EXPQRY  ARExpandQueryMenu --  from Mid-tier (protocol 23) at IP address 10.122.0.61 using RPC // :q:0.0s 

<FLTR> <TID: 0000000457> <RPC ID: 0072646830> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:19.5660 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:1> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_GetLabel" (502)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000345> <RPC ID: 0072647870> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:30.4330 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:3> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_3" (530)

<FLTR> <TID: 0000000441> <RPC ID: 0072647871> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:30.4480 */ --> Disabled -- filter is ignored
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000460> <RPC ID: 0072648393> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390620   > <USER: esribar                                      > <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:35.3710 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:123> Checking "INT:SRMHPD:INC:UpdateRequest_99_SetSRAppRegistryGUID" (99)

<FLTR> <TID: 0000000460> <RPC ID: 0072648393> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390620   > <USER: esribar                                      > <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:35.4250 */ Application-Copy-Field-Value 600000001 1000003890
<SQL > <TID: 0000000457> <RPC ID: 0000000000> <Queue: Admin     > <Client-RPC: 390600   > <USER:                                              > <Overlay-Group: 0         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:41.8550 */ Generating prepared statement

<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072648992> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:41.9020 */ --> Disabled -- filter is ignored
<SQL > <TID: 0000000346> <RPC ID: 0072649991> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:51.9350 */ COMMIT TRANSACTION

<API > <TID: 0000000439> <RPC ID: 0072650203> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:53.7280 */ +CE      ARCreateEntry -- schema FB:History from Flashboards (protocol 22) at IP address 10.122.26.197 using RPC // :q:0.0s 
<SQL > <TID: 0007483686> <RPC ID: 0000000000> <Queue: Escalation> <Client-RPC: 0        > <USER:                                              > <Overlay-Group: 0         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 14:06:48.7630 */ Generating prepared statement

<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0000000000> <Queue: Admin     > <Client-RPC: 390600   > <USER:                                              > <Overlay-Group: 0         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 14:06:52.1940 */ OK
<SQL > <TID: 0000000457> <RPC ID: 0072764627> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 14:18:10.5700 */ OK
```

See those TIDs? Every element that occurs, has it's own thread ID, so one element can have for example 100 TIDs scattered through one .log file.

How can I go about capturing the TIDs, when a timeout happens (previousLine), searching for that TID across the original .log file, and exporting every line referencing that TID into a new file (and of course doing that for every timeout that does happen)?

With a new regex / DateTime function? Is it possible to only get the TIDs (as they are always the same for elements, RPC IDs and the rest are not - one TID happens twice in this output "TID: 0000000447", but is different from one another).

This is how my code looks so far:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace LogParser
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        var counterLine = 0;
        var counterTimeout = 0;
        var line = string.Empty;
        var previousLine = string.Empty;
        var previousDt = DateTime.MaxValue;
        var tidLine = string.Empty;
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{4}");

        try
        {
            var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Profesionalno branje logov se začenja:\n");

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "log_output.txt"), true))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    counterLine++;
                    foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(line))
                    {
                        var dt = new DateTime();
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "HH:mm:ss.ffff", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                        {
                            if ((dt - previousDt).TotalSeconds > 1)
                            {
                                counterTimeout++;
                                Console.WriteLine(previousLine);
                                Console.WriteLine(line + "\n\n\n");
                                writer.WriteLine(previousLine);
                                writer.WriteLine(line + Environment.NewLine);
                            }

                            previousLine = line;
                            previousDt = dt;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            file.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("\nBranje logov je končano. Prebrali smo: {0} vrstic ter izpisali " +
                              "{1} vrstic, kjer je bil timeout v datoteko.", counterLine, counterTimeout);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.OpenStandardError();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.OpenStandardError();
            Console.WriteLine("Uporaba: {0} LOG_FILE", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

End result should look something like this (for every TID):

```
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5920 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:2> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs" (505)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5920 */ --> Disabled -- filter is ignored
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5930 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:2> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_1" (510)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5930 */ --> Disabled -- filter is ignored
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5930 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:2> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_2" (520)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         >    --> Passed -- perform actions
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         >         0 : Set Fields
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5940 */ Generating prepared statement
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5950 */ OK
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5950 */ Binding [5] parameters to prepared statement
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5950 */ OK
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5950 */ WITH AR_SQL_Alias$1 AS (SELECT T72.C179, T72.C1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T72.C1 ASC) AS 'AR_RowNumber_Alias$1' FROM T72 WHERE ((N'{78DF8F98-D170-48A2-A7A8-0B2E2BB6931C}' = T72.C179) AND ((T72.C41050 = N'CMDB:Total_Base_CI') OR (T72.C41050 = N'CMDB:Total_Relationship_CI')))) SELECT AR_SQL_Alias$1.C179, AR_SQL_Alias$1.C1 FROM AR_SQL_Alias$1 WHERE (AR_SQL_Alias$1.AR_RowNumber_Alias$1 BETWEEN 0 AND 3)
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5960 */ OK
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         >               Label Group5 (40111) = 
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5960 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:3> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_3" (530)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         >    --> Failed qualification
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5960 */ <Filter Level:0 Number Of Filters:4> Checking "FB:SetGroupForSmartReportingKPIs_4" (540)
<FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         >    --> Failed qualification
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0000000000> <Queue: Admin     > <Client-RPC: 390600   > <USER:                                              > <Overlay-Group: 0         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5980 */ OK
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5980 */ INSERT INTO T251(C7,C40000,C40100,C40104,C40106,C40108,C40102,C40101,C40103,C40105,C40107,C40109,C2,C8,C5,C3,C6,C1) VALUES(0,N'{78DF8F98-D170-48A2-A7A8-0B2E2BB6931C}',1000000164,1000000217,1000000001,303497300,1358879400,2.00,N'2',N'TS3111 Merilni sistemi',N'Telekom Slovenije, d.d.',N'INTERNET_11894970',N'Remedy Application Service',N'x',N'Remedy Application Service',1519649528,1519649528,N'000000118010138')
<SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072599594> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:52:08.5990 */ OK
```

And so on and so forth (there's a lot of lines, so I cut them out).

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: How I want the second output to look like? Like so:

    <FLTR> <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0072648992> <Queue: Fast      > <Client-RPC: 390619   > <USER: Remedy Application Service -- Impersonated by Remedy Application Service --> <Overlay-Group: 1         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 13:58:41.9020 */ --> Disabled -- filter is ignored
    <SQL > <TID: 0000000447> <RPC ID: 0000000000> <Queue: Admin     > <Client-RPC: 390600   > <USER:                                              > <Overlay-Group: 0         > /* Mon Feb 26 2018 14:06:52.1940 */ OK

Comment: And all of the rest of the 0000000447 TIDs from the 2GB log file. And after it outputs the first one it finds (from the first OUTPUT), it does a new blank line, and it pastes the second TIDs, blank line, third TIDs, etc.

But when it gets the TIDs it also copies the whole line from the log file, exactly like my output I'm creating right now.

Comment: Edit your post and add end result. What do you want regex to output?

Comment: There you go. What's important is that it gets the TID that happend at the timeout in my first output, and searches for it in the original log and copies all of it from the .log into a new file.

And it has to do that for every TID it finds as a timeout (at least once) in the first output.

Comment: Research Regex: named capture groups, back references and perhaps lookahead statements. Go to http://regexpal.com (use PCRE rather than Javascript engine) and go nuts, plenty of tutorials, you can find many examples on these topics there and on google.

Comment: Come back with more to-the-point questions! This is basically a "do my work for me" request as it stands.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel like this, but that wasn't the point. I never asked anyone to write code for me, I'm just stuck at one of the functions this program will have, and I wanted to get an outsiders view on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of trouble following what you want and I just copied both your input and desired output but I cannot understand what exactly is the pattern your seek. If you could give a simplified example, that would help since Regex is pretty much that with a variable pattern.

Based on what you asked though, here's a workflow I'd recommend:

Use a while loop where Regex.IsMatch is the condition. While you are always matching your condition, the loop keeps going and extracts your info.

For the matching pattern itself, based on what you are asking, look for what a timeout pattern looks like (I cannot tell) and you can use that to take the next line:

```
(timeoutpattern.*[\r\n]+).*
```

This will match the timeoutpattern itself but would be needed in the loop.

While this match is made and saved as a string variable, remove it from the original string using Regex.Replace and replace it with `""`

Then replace from the original string the (timeoutpattern).*? with "" to remove it entirely (you get your desired output).

Comment: Hi!

[This is how the first log looks like](https://pastebin.com/9uP2kzx9) (the one I'm parsing). In my OP, the first piece of information is how the log looks like after I parse it for the first time. Then there's my code. And the third piece of information in my OP is how I would like the **second** output to look like (extracted all TIDs (thread IDs)), that match one timeout (and I would like to do that for every timeout).

I was told by someone that I should use dictionaries, and store all lines in there, and then just extract them from there after I find a timeout.

Best regards!